# Creating a 'Custom Designer' Visual Studio 2010 Add-in

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, editor, add-in, visual-studio-addins

A major part of our work is creating and manipulating certain XML files, for which have a custom editor. The editor is starting to get creaky and we are looking at building a replacement. Since **VS2010** has recently arrived, ostensibly with an improved add-in architecture (MEF?), I am interested in the possibility of building the editor as **a custom editor within Visual Studio**.

It would have to **appear in the same way as the code editor or the Designer** - a tab item, of which there can be many open at once, containing the GUI we use to edit the files. It would **integrate with VS's Edit menu**. It could **use the output window to display messages**. It would appear **the same as any other editor within Visual Studio**.

Right now, I am looking for **examples of add-ins that work in a similar way** - ideally with source code - to see whether this model would suit our requirements. I am also looking for any **documentation or tutorials** relevant to creating a VS2010 add-in, or information about VS2008 add-ins if this is still relevant.

Any input is welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want to look at the [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/) for VS 2010.  Since 2010 is written in .net you can create add on components using it.

[Code editor extension](http://www.visualstudiounleashed.com/mikesnell/post/2010/04/Visual-Studio-2010-MEF-Code-Editor-Extension-ndash3b-Code-Camp-Pittsburgh-2010.aspx) for VS 2010.

[Working with MEF](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/04/01/working-with-mef.aspx)

[Custom Editor Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd885122.aspx)

Update:
Since someone asked in a comment, I thought I would post this link on creating add ons for vs 2008: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb968855.aspx

Comment: can I conclude from your links that this is not possible yet in Visual Studio 2008, only from 2010 on?

Comment: @jan: Now I've never done this, but from what I understand you can created VS 2008 add ons, actually if you do a search, you can find companies that have created them.  From what I understand it is tedious, and time consuming but possible.